# pasar valores a función php

Tags: php

Quiero pasar unos valores a una funcion de php y no tengo muy claro como hacerlo y el manual de php no me ayuda mucho.

la funcion que tengo seria esta:

```
function Control_Stock($Operacion,$Ean,$Cantidad) { 
    $ean = substr ($Ean, 0, 12); //eliminamos el caracter 13
    return $ean;
}
```

y en la llamada entiendo que tengo que definir esos valores. ¿Seria algo así?

```
ControlStock('+','8424433011921','32');
```

lo estoy haciendo tipo javascript pero me da un error y no se si es que no estoy pasando bien los valores, si es que no se pasan asi o si tengo algo mal en el codigo de la función. En principio el contenido de la función seria lo de menos, lo único que necesito es que los valores de `$Operacion,$Ean,$Cantidad` pasen y se puedan usar.

Comment: Tu función se llama Control_Stock, y la mandas a llamar ControlStock,
que error te marca si no es ese?

Comment: ¡¡Anda!! eso es lo que se llama literalmente estar gilipollas XD mira que no darme cuenta... ¿Entonces los datos que quiero que tengan los valores $Operacion, $Ean, $Cantidad se pasan como lo estoy haciendo? @Sr1871

Comment: sí, así están  bien para más información http://php.net/manual/es/language.functions.php

Comment: Pues muchísimas gracias @Sr1871y perdona por estar tan atontao y no ver el _ de diferencia :_(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, es exactamente así como se hace (pero ten cuidado que en el segundo código has copiado mal el nombre de la función). Otro ejemplo:

1. Definir función

   `function SumaDosNumeros($input1, $input2){
       return $input1 + $input2;
   }`
2. Llamar a la función

   `SumaDosNumeros(1,2);`

Ten en cuenta que:

- Esto actúa como una variable, si quieres mostrar el resultado en la pantalla puedes utilizar el siguiente código: `echo SumaDosNumeros(1,2);`. Otra opción es incluir un echo dentro de la función en lugar de un return, si no quieres utilizar el dato sino solo mostrarlo en pantalla. También puedes guardar el resultado en una variable (`$suma = SumaDosNumeros(1,2);`).
- Puedes utilizar variables en lugar de los números (ej.: `$numero1=1; $numero2=2; echo SumaDosNumeros($numero1,$numero2);`), y debes poner comillas si utilizas strings de tipo texto (ej.: `function MiFuncion($nombre, $apellido){return 'El nombre es ' . $nombre . ' y el apellido es ' . $apellido;} echo MiFuncion('Anacleto','Martinez');`)

Sé que me he extendido bastante y seguramente ya sabrás casi todas o todas estas cosas pero siempre pienso en los usuarios que encuentran la pregunta buscando en google o incluso dentro de stack overflow algo que esté relacionado y les puede servir esta información.

¡Un saludo!

Comment: Siempre se puede aprender algo nuevo y en efecto una respuesta así no solo me ayuda a mi, si no que ayuda a otras personas que tengan un problema similar  muchas gracias por la respuesta, no te doy mis dies porque solo se puede dar un voto, que si no te votaba más.